# Достать часть строки из строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Привет!

У меня есть строка следующего вида: **/что-либо/что-либо/что-либо/.../что-либо/***что-либо*

Нужно достать с помощью регулярных выражений часть строки выделенную *курсивом* и часть строки выделенную **жирным**. С регулярными выражениями знаком не сильно и поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможный пример [реализации](http://ideone.com/sXWkTk)

Answer (score 2):

если я правильно понял, регулярки вам не нужны. попробуйте использовать [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

Comment: Нужно с помощью регулярки для роута в Kohana, про Explode я и так знаю. Спасибо.

Comment: в смысле надо сделать dirname ? т.е. прсто строку
 `/что-либо/что-либо/что-либо/.../что-либо/` ?

       #/[^/]+$#